# How to make an application that floats on the desktop in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, toolbar, windows-8.1, floating

I would like to develop an application for Windows 8 that floats on the desktop. It is just a simple tool bar containing a could sliders and send their values to some calculation software. I would like the tool bar to float on top of everything like the On-Screen Keyboard. I do not want a Metro UI application. Is this possible?

Kind regards,
Drew

Comment: Create a window and make it topmost. Hope that nobody else does the same.

Comment: Thank you David, I will give it a try and let you know how I get on.